# onClick event and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, onclick

I am using the jQuery dialog box that is found at this [link](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form)  and I am trying to get it to open with an onClick event, not by use of a button. It works in Firefox and Chrome, but will not work in IE. If you go to my test site and click on the upper left (first one) box, you will see it brings up a dialog in FF and Chrome, but there is no select "hand" cursor in IE8 or IE9. 
http://calmaps.co.calumet.wi.us/datapopuptest.html
I am not proficient in JavaScript, but I am just using an example, so I did not write the code, just changed some of the text to meet my needs.

The javascript im trying to call in the html:

```
$( "#request-data" )
  //.button()
  .click(function() {
    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
  });
```

my html calling the javascript:

```
<a id="request-data" title="Municipal Boundary Data" onclick= "$('#request-data').click(function() {$('#dialog-form').dialog('open');
    return false;})" href="PleaseEnableJavascript.html"><img src="img/muni.png" alt="Calumet Municipal Boundaries" /></a>
```

Like I said, this works in Chrome and Firefox, but I get nothing in IE, no error, just nothing. I have spent a day researching this issue and I'm hoping I can get some insight.  Thanks!

Comment: You have to put JS code in a `<script>` file, not inside a `onclick` attribute

Comment: don't need `onClick` on `request-data` if above script already defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stuartd already pointed out the different solutions, I created a js fiddle for you with one suggestion to avoid the default a click function.

This is the relevant part:

```
$( "#create-user" )
      .css('cursor','pointer') //some css for a pointer
      .click(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

Here you'll find the js-fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JBqzU/

And it was already said, there's no need to include inline js into your a-tag.

Edit:

Here you are, did some jslint standards, but i dont think this will fix the problems as suggested at the comments, you have to run through your whole js code. I think you have problem there, cause testing the snippet at fiddle for ie works fine.

Good Luck anyway.

```
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    var name = $("#name"),
        email = $("#email"),
        organization = $("#organization"),
        allFields = $([]).add(name).add(email).add(organization),
        tips = $(".validateTips");

    function updateTips(t) {
        tips
            .text(t)
            .addClass("ui-state-highlight");
        setTimeout(function () {
            tips.removeClass("ui-state-highlight", 1500);
        }, 500);
    }

    function checkLength(o, n, min, max) {
        if (o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min) {
            o.addClass("ui-state-error");
            updateTips("Length of " + n + " must be between " + min + " and " + max + ".");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    function checkRegexp(o, regexp, n) {
        if (!(regexp.test(o.val()))) {
            o.addClass("ui-state-error");
            updateTips(n);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    $("#dialog-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Show Me The Data": function () {
                var bValid = true;
                allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");
                bValid = bValid && checkLength(name, "name", 3, 25);
                bValid = bValid && checkLength(email, "email", 6, 80);
                bValid = bValid && checkLength(organization, "organization", 5, 25);
                bValid = bValid && checkRegexp(name, /^[a-z\-\s]+$/i, "Name may consist of letters only.");
                // From jquery.validate.js (by joern), contributed by Scott Gonzalez: http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
                bValid = bValid && checkRegexp(email, /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i, "Email must be valid - eg. ui@jquery.com");
                bValid = bValid && checkRegexp(email, /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i, "Email must be valid - eg. ui@jquery.com");
                bValid = bValid && checkRegexp(organization, /^([0-9a-zA-Z\-\s])+$/, "Organization field only allows : a-z 0-9");

                if (bValid) {
                    $("#users tbody").append("<tr>" +
                                               "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" +
                                               "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" +
                                               "<td>" + organization.val() + "</td>" +
                                               "</tr>");
                    location.href = "ftp://liouser:l!oguest1@ftp.co.calumet.wi.us/websitedata/CalumetBoundaries.zip";
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        close: function () {
            allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
        }
    });

    $("#request-data")
        .css('cursor', 'pointer')
        .click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
        });
});
```

Comment: Fist of all, thank you all for the help. I'm so green at JavaScript and HTML it's sick. Thank you for your patience. Ok, I put the JS code you have above into the JS portion of my page. I then removed the onClick event in my HTML, relying on the id to get the html to call the JS (I hope my understanding is correct), and it remains nonfunctional in IE, but it still works in FF and Chrome. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: hey there, i've tested the version you posted located here http://calmaps.co.calumet.wi.us/datapopuptest.html
Dont know if you did changes already here, but in ie9 with opened developer tools(f12) the dialog shows up.

Comment: Checking your code snippet actually, will take a time. But I cant check your whole js, pls make sure that you don't have a console output anywhere at your scripts or google for a console bug fix for ie. I ran into this problems when I started scripting very often :)

Comment: Using everyones help I finally got it to work. It had to do with how IE works with CSS. It would not run the script due to a css hover option. If I moved the code up so that IE would see the js before it did the hover, then it would work in IE, but no other browser. Using an <!--[ifIE]> fixed the problem and now everything seems to work. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 2):

Given that in `onclick` you're defining the [click handler](http://api.jquery.com/click/) for the element (ie when you click it you're telling it what to do when it's clicked), the fact that it works in *any* browser the first time you click it is a testament to Postel's law.

You can either change the onclick to just do what you need:

```
onclick= "$('#dialog-form').dialog('open') ..
```

Or make it call a function:

```
function showDialog() { .. }

onclick= "showDialog()"
```

Or you could just assign the click handler in `document.ready`, and then you don't need anything in `onclick`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#request-data").click(function() {
        $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
     });
});
```

Comment: I'd suggest the second option, otherwise you're kinda missing the point of using jQuery.

Comment: @stuartd Please forgive my ignorance, but when I put the $(document).ready... block into my code, it just messes up the page by putting the dialog box fields that are supposed to be in the new window on the main webpage. I assumed I needed to remove the onClick event from the html, which I did and it still didn't work. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

One of the whole points of using jQuery is that you can define your click events without using `onclick` in the HTML.

The `$(...).click()` method is not intended for use inside an `onclick` attribute.

Write the jQuery click handler in your `$(document).ready()` function and take it out of the HTML.

Hope that helps.